# RX challenge 5 complex event processing using LINQ language integrated query (Spoiler Alert)

Tags: c#, system.reactive

In the [complex event processing workshop](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Rx-Workshop/Rx-Workshop-Event-Processing) on the RX site, challenge 5 is done using a Buffer. I have a solution using LINQ dot or lamba notation. Out of interest I'd like to convert it to the LINQ language integrated query notation.

The challenge and my code follow. For some reason `result2` doesn't work properly, it makes the UI unresponsive and the output looks truncated. Is this something funky, is it my query, can you fix it?

The Challenge (Download [here](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/content/RxWorkshop/Challenge5.zip))

```
IObservable<object> Query(IObservable<StockQuote> quotes)
{
    // TODO: Change the query below to compute the average high and average low over
    //       the past five trading days as well as the current close and date.
    // HINT: Try using Buffer.

    return from quote in quotes
           where quote.Symbol == "MSFT"
           select new { quote.Close, quote.Date };
}
```

My solution

```
IObservable<object> Query(IObservable<StockQuote> quotes)
{
    // TODO: Change the query below to compute the average high and average low over
    //       the past five trading days as well as the current close and date.
    // HINT: Try using Buffer.

    var result1 = quotes.Where(qt => qt.Symbol == "MSFT").Buffer(5, 1).Select(quoteList =>
    {
        var avg = quoteList.Average(qt => qt.Close);
        return new { avg, quoteList.Last().Close, quoteList.Last().Date };
    });

    var result2 = from quote in quotes
                  where quote.Symbol == "MSFT"
                  from quoteList in quotes.Buffer(5, 1)
                  let avg = quoteList.Average(qt => qt.Close)
                  select new { avg, quoteList.Last().Close, quoteList.Last().Date };

    return result2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions subscribe to quotes multiple times (even more than two times - remember multiple from clauses result in a SelectMany call under the hood), so there's already something wrong there :-). Try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the query should look more like this:

```
        var result =
            from quote in quotes
            where quote.Symbol == "MSFT"
            from quoteList in quotes.Buffer(5, 1)
            let avgHigh = quoteList.Average(qt => qt.High)
            let avgLow = quoteList.Average(qt => qt.Low)
            select new { avgHigh, avgLow, quote.Close, quote.Date };
```

But this has only minor differences to yours - only that there is no need to do `quoteList.Last()` when `quote` would do & the question asked for the average of `High` & `Low`, not the `Close`.

From what I can tell the issue is to do with the chart and not with the Rx component. I think the chart is redrawing so often that it is blocking.

Comment: I tried this approach initially, but it has the same problems as above and also produces multiple output lines. The issue may be to do with the chart updating, but then why does the Labmda version i.e. `result1` work so well?

Comment: I feel a bit foolish. I've turned a chained `Select` into a single `SelectMany`. That's what's wrong. The `result1` is the right way to go.

Comment: The final stream is bound to the buffered stream so the current value updates only once in 5 times.

Comment: @Asti - Because it's a `SelectMany` it's producing "n-squared" values where n is the number of elements of the `quotes` sequence. That's what was killing the chart.

Answer (score 0):

The problem requires that both graphs (current, average) be drawn simultaneously.
I don't believe it's possible to use the bind monad (`SelectMany`) to independently compose the latest values of those two streams which is specified by the problem.

Comprehensions downward of `quotes.Buffer` would be bound to the rate of the buffered stream.

Alternatively:

```
        quotes = quotes.Publish().RefCount();
        return Observable.CombineLatest
            (
                first: quotes,
                second: quotes.Buffer(5, 1).Select(
                        buffer => new { High = buffer.Average(q => q.High), Low = buffer.Average(q => q.Low) }),
                resultSelector: (l, r) => new { l.Close, l.Date, r.High, r.Low }
            );
```

moves at the same rate as the source resulting in a smooth graph.

Comment: Hi Asti, thanks for the answer, I don't understand it though, can you expand / explain more?. Plugging it in also doesn't work, as CombineLatest can't infer type arguments. Putting `<StockQuote, dynamic, object>` in, will make it compile but nothing comes out on the chart.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't compile. 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1928972/Share/Challenge5.zip
A built version is in the `bin` folder.

Comment: It works by combining the latest values of two streams, the first stream has all the quotes, the second stream produces the average high and low values every 5 times. The `resultSelector` decides how to combine the two streams.

Comment: Still no go I'm afraid. Compiler error: `The type arguments for method 'System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.CombineLatest<TFirst,TSecond,TResult>(System.IObservable<TFirst>, System.IObservable<TSecond>, System.Func<TFirst,TSecond,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` And no result on graph.

Comment: @SDK Try replacing the `new {...}` with `new StockQuote {...}`